Как получить юзера telegram из веб приложения flet
Имеется web приложение для телеграма, написанное на питоне с библиотекой flet. Допустим название: app.py. Оно запускается из бота в тг, допустим название: bot.py. Как можно получить данные о юзере, который запустил сайт в скрипте app.py? Я могу получать юзеров из bot.py, но никак не могу передать эти значения в app.py

Telegram отправляет запросы на твой сайт с flet аргументы с данными юзера, и вроде в flet нельзя читать полученые аргументы со страницы. В документации telegram web-apps показан javascript, на котором обычно пилят веб приложения
